# Complexification of a Lie subalgebra of a compact real form

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

I'm currently reading the paper [Lie algebra Cohomology and the Generalized Borel–Weil theorem](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Ejml/kostant61.pdf) written by B. Kostant, and I have a question about Remark 3.9 he made.

In this paper, $\mathfrak{g}$ is a complex semisimple Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{t}$ is its [compact real form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_form_(Lie_theory)#Compact_real_form). Using the decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{t}\oplus i\mathfrak{t}$ the author defines the complex conjugate $\ast$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ by defining $(a+ib)^{\ast}=-a+ib$ for $a,b\in\mathfrak{t}$. (He uses the subspace $i\mathfrak{t}$ as a real part.) In Remark 3.9 of the paper, the author mentions that

> In case $\mathfrak{a}$ is a Lie subalgebra and $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}^{\ast}$ it follows that $\mathfrak{a}$ is necessarily reductive in $\mathfrak{g}$ since it clearly arises as the complexification of a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{t}$.

First of all, it was not clear to me what does it mean by saying that $\mathfrak{a}$ is reductive ‘in’ $\mathfrak{g}$. Does it simply mean that $\mathfrak{a}$ is a reductive Lie algebra? Secondly, if it means that $\mathfrak{a}$ is a reductive Lie algebra, then I am curious why the fact that $\mathfrak{a}$ arises as a complexification of a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{t}$ implies that $\mathfrak{a}$ is reductive.

Answer (score 7):

Historically, I think the paper may simply be early enough that it wasn't clear whether the various notions of reductivity in characteristic $0$ were equivalent.  “Reductive in $\mathfrak g$” could mean, for example, that the adjoint representation on $\mathfrak g$ was completely reducible.

A Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak k$ is the Lie algebra of a compact group, so its complexification is the Lie algebra of the complexification of a compact group, which is reductive.

(By the way, the letter is a Fraktur k, $\mathfrak k$ `\mathfrak k`, not a Fraktur t, $\mathfrak t$ `\mathfrak t` (setting aside the usual issues of Fraktur vs. [Sütterlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlin), for which you can read elsewhere on MO ([e.g.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5853/blackboard-rendering-of-math-fonts#comment654159_6007))).  This matters to the extent that it is *very* hard for a Lie theorist, or at least for me, to read $\mathfrak t$ as being anything other than the Lie algebra of a torus.)